# Pass data from client to server. Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i'm little stuck on my express application.

I have a file index.js in routes folder and I want to save the result of **mydata**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', token, function(req, res, next) {
  var mydata = req.userId

  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Welcolme',
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And, in my other file (which depends on app.js), I would like to get and pass **mydata** to the server

```
var app = require('../app');

server.listen(port, function () {
  require('../assets/js/server/socket')(server, mydata);
});
```

(Here is my app.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'twig');

app.use('/', indexRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

And the socket file

```
var io = {};

module.exports = (server, mydata) => {
  console.log('Hello : ' , mydata)

  io = require('socket.io')(server);

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Connected')
  });
};
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you :)

Comment: How does your app.js look like and why do you want to pass userId to the other file which depends on app.js?

Comment: the user id is part of the token and I need it, it lets me know on which database I will use socketio side

Comment: Can you show us the code in the socket.js as well? Plus why don't you start the server in the app.js together but instead in a separate file? Just a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, you are right but the code is quite long (it's why i separate files), I put just the critical part for more readability :))

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Let me add my potential solution to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of still having this `route.get('/') ...`

You can let the user enter the data and have it transferred directly through the WebSocket connection.

Example:

```
//Client-side

//Get the user data somewhere from the HTML page
const userData = document.getElementbyId("some html element's id here").innerHTML;

//Send it to the back end
socket.emit('userData',userData)

//Open a listener to get the data from the back end later
socket.on('processedData',processedData=>{

//Use it in the way you desired.

});



//Server-side
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 console.log('Connected')

socket.on('userData',userData=>{
 //Do something here, like validation and stuff

socket.emit('processedData','processedData here')
});


});
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, I hadn't thought of this idea, I tested it works :)